# Black circles instead of images in Corona

Tags: android, image, lua, coronasdk

I'm new to Corona and coding in general, and am currently playing around with app reskinning. I am attempting to add my own images to a game, and at this point I am getting black circles instead of my chosen images, while everything else in the game seems to be fine. This is what the code was before:

```
Ball_Player = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (25 * ((GameScreen.width  * (_H / 1300))) / 600)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player.alpha = 0;

Ball_Player1 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (25 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 700)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player1:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player1.alpha = 0;

Ball_Player2 = display.newCircle( Player2X, Player2Y, (25 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 700)) --(9 +((7 - PlayerSpeed) * 5 ))
Ball_Player2:setFillColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
Ball_Player2.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy1 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy1:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy1.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy2 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy2:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy2.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy3 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy3:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy3.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy4 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy4:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy4.alpha = 0;

Ball_Enemy5 = display.newCircle( PlayerX, PlayerY, (35 * ((GameScreen.width * (_H / 1300))) / 600));
Ball_Enemy5:setFillColor(0.8, 0.2, 0.2);
Ball_Enemy5.alpha = 0;
```

And these are the changes I made. At this point, I am really just piecing things together from tutorials online, so any and all guidance is welcome! Thanks!

```
Ball_Player = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5)  
Ball_Player.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Player.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Player.fill = {"images/playerearth.png"}

Ball_Player1 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5 )
Ball_Player1.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Player1.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Player1.fill = {"images/playerearth.png"}

Ball_Player2 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5)
Ball_Player2.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Player2.x = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Player2.fill = {"images/playermoon.png"}

Ball_Enemy1 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5)
Ball_Enemy1.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Enemy1.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Enemy1.fill = {"images/enemy1.png"}

Ball_Enemy2 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5)
Ball_Enemy2.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Enemy2.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Enemy2.fill = {"images/enemy2.png"}

Ball_Enemy3 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5 )
Ball_Enemy3.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Enemy3.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Enemy3.fill = {"images/enemy3.png"}

Ball_Enemy4 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5 )
Ball_Enemy4.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Enemy4.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Enemy4.fill = {"images/enemy4.png"}

Ball_Enemy5 = display.newCircle( 0, 0, 31.5 )
Ball_Enemy5.x = display.contentCenterX
Ball_Enemy5.y = display.contentCenterY
Ball_Enemy5.fill = {"images/enemy5.png"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the right parameters for the fill.  Example:

```
Ball_Enemy4.fill = {type="image", filename="images/enemy4.png"}
```